# texture images override using andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using andengine. I used one texture for two texture region

```
 public Texture xImg;

 public TextureRegion xRegion,yRegion;

this.xImg=new Texture(64, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);  

this.xRegion= TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.xImg, this, "level.png", 0, 0);

this.yRegion= TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.xImg, this, "life.png", 0, 0);
```

I created a two sprite for xRegion and yRegion. But two sprite images is override with level and life images. How to share one texture  for two texture region

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use

```
this.myBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

this.xRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "level.png", 0, 0);
this.yRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "life.png", 50, 0);
```

last 2 values in the constructor of textureRegion specify location for your region in TextureAtlas. So you have to use different x,y values

check this for more examples [andengine examples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/#hg/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples)

Comment: Using old version of andengine. BitmapTextureAtlas not found. If i changed latest jar, i need change so many line in my coding . Any other solution

Comment: just change last 2 values in your constructor of textureregion because it cant be 0,0 and 0,0 it depends of your image sizes. if your images have size 32x32 then use 0,0 and 32,0

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the situation, the Texture used in AndEngine is just a huge picture where you place smaller pictures by using createFromAsset method. I believe it works that way because of some low-level OpenGL ES trick that increases performance.

If you set your coordinates wrong, the pictures will overlap in the Texture and when you display them later, you will see a part of the image that was added later in the picture that you added onto the Texture earlier.

Also, in newer versions of AndEngine, there is a new class BuildableTexture that uses some clever algorithm to place the pictures for you automagically.
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/buildabletextures-t415.html